# What is the syntax error in this OpenAI API function calling?

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, openai-api

I'm attempting to utilize function calling within my request to the OpenAI API, but I'm encountering a syntax error that eludes my detection. Could someone please assist me in identifying the issue?

That's the code

```
message = "me chamo erick rocha e faço ciência da computação da universidade veiga de almeida, eu sou um brasileiro de 21 anos e tem um CR de 8, ele é conhecido por ser um excelente programador e por estar explorando vários campos da computação, atuamente estágia na puc rio em um projeto de inteligência de computação"

prompt = f'''   extraia as informações do texto integre e retorne como um arquivo JSON object:

nome
universidade
idade
CR

esse é o texto base:
{message}
'''

client = OpenAI(api_key=mykey)
response =  client.chat.completions.create(
        model="gpt-3.5-turbo",
        messages = [{"role":"user" , "content":prompt}],
        functions = student_custom_function
    )
```

and that's the function calling:

```
student_custom_function = [
    {
        "type": "function",
        "function": {
            'name': 'extrair_info_estudante',
            'description': 'retirar informações do estudante com base no texto enviado',
            'parameters': {
                'type': 'object',
                'properties': {
                    'nome': {
                        'type': 'string',
                        'description': 'Nome da pessoa'
                    },
                    'universidade': {
                        'type': 'string',
                        'description': 'O nome da Universidade'
                    },
                    'idade': {
                        'type': 'integer',
                        'description': 'A idade do estudante'
                    },
                    'CR': {
                        'type': 'integer',
                        'description': 'O CR do estudante'
                    },
                },
                 "required": ["name","nome", "universidade" , "idade" , "CR"],
            },
        }
    }
    ]
```

I aimed to make the function calls simulate a form of prompt engineering, but unfortunately, it's not functioning as expected. Currently, I'm encountering the following error:

```
Error code: 400 - {'error': {'message': "'name' is a required property - 'functions.0'", 
'type': 'invalid_request_error', 'param': None, 'code': None}}
```

However, I'm uncertain if this single error is the sole cause of the issue. Can someone assist me in troubleshooting?

Comment: Maybe `"required": ["name"` ... But `name` is not in the `properties` object. Why do you need `nome` and `name`? And where do you set the other "required" values?